# Split string on non alphanumeric characters using awk

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk

I'm trying to get the last substring before a non alphanumeric character. For eg.

1) beta gamma foo

2) beta gamma%foo

3) beta gamma|---foo

In all of the above examples I'm trying to get "foo" as it is the last substring after splitting on non-alphanumeric characters

So far I've tried

```
cat file* | awk -F'[^:alnum:]' '{print $NF;}' | less
```

but this doesn't give the expected results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your POSIX regex is incorrect. Use this `awk` command:

```
awk -F '[^[:alnum:]]' '{print $NF}' file
foo
foo
foo
```